# Connecting to geth docker server via RPC over HTTP from other container with docker-compose: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url

Tags: docker, docker-compose, go-ethereum

I am trying to connect to an geth node in a docker container via RPC over HTTP. It works fine when I connect from the host and use the URL http://localhost:8545 with the Web3.HTTPProvider instance in a Python web application; however when I try to connect from inside another container using the docker-compose name of the service for the server (http://ethereum:8545), I get the follwing error message:

`docker-compose-web-1       | requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 403 Client Error: Forbidden for url: http://ethereum:8545`

My docker-compose.yml is the following:

```
services:
  web:
    image: cramananjaona/minimalapp:0.0.1
    ports:
      - "8088:8088"
    links:
      - ethereum
  ethereum:
    image: cramananjaona/tabouret:0.0.1
    ports:
      - 8545:8545
      - 30303:30303
```

The Dockerfile for ethereum is

```
FROM alpine:latest
RUN apk update
RUN apk add geth
COPY node02 node02
CMD ["geth", "--datadir", "node02", "--port", "30303", "--nodiscover", "--http", "--http.api", "eth,net,web3,admin", "--http.addr", "0.0.0.0", "--networkid", "1900"]
```

Is there a particular option which need to be passed to docker or geth to make this work?

Comment: Are you adding any authentication/authorization block in your Python web application? Can you share the application .py files here?

Comment: No, there is no authentication in the application. The Python application fails on `print(web3.eth.getBalance(account)*1e-18)`, there is no need for authentication to execute this function.

Comment: Here is a minimal python example which fails when run in docker:
    ```from web3 import Web3  

    def main():  
    web3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider('http://ethereum:8545'))  
    account = "0xc096a34cFC2094D360373CC631eB28f353F4498e"  
    print(web3.eth.getBalance(account)*1e-18)  

if __name__=="__main__":  
    main()```

Comment: I pushed the two docker images on dockerhub: cramananjaona/minimalapp for the python application and cramananjaona/tabouret for the go-ethereum private testnet rpc server.

Answer (score 0):

you need to tell geth to allow connection from hosts.
with `--http.vhosts=*`

```
CMD ["geth", "--datadir", "node02", "--port", "30303", "--nodiscover", "--http", "--http.api", "eth,net,web3,admin", "--http.addr", "0.0.0.0", "--networkid", "1900", "--http.vhosts", "*"]
```